# C++ Game Clock Timer

Tags: c++, clock

I have this code that makes a working timer that fits perfectly for my game! It does everything right, their is just once small issue. When ever the clockTicker less than 10, the clock displays the time like 0:4, instead I want it to display like 0:04. I tried this code out, cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << clockTicker. Which works perfectly! The 0 will only in front of the number when it's less than 10! But I need to save the clockTicker in a text document for my game also, which technically. The 0 doesn't "save" itself in front of the int. So my question is, if the clockTicker is less than zero, how can I add a 0 in front of the number, AND save it into the variable like so. Example: 0:08. 1:04

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void clickTime(int &, int, const int);  // Timer for the display clock

//---- Display Clock----------------------------------------
const int Time = 0;
int Minute = 0;
int loopRepeats = 0;
int clockTicker = Time; 

bool stoptimer = false;
// Set position of text
void CPos(int x, int y)
{
    COORD cPos;
    cPos.X = x;
    cPos.Y = y; 
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cPos);
    }
int main()
{

    while(stoptimer == false)
    {
        clickTime(clockTicker,loopRepeats,Time);
        loopRepeats++;
        CPos(0, 0); cout << " Time is:         ";
        cout << Minute << ":" << clockTicker;
        Sleep(100);     // This is the game of the game's speed
    }

    return 0;
}

void clickTime(int &time, int loops, const int Time)
{
if(stoptimer == false)
{
    // This tells the program after the loop repeats 7 times, to decrement a second!
     if((loops % 8) == 7){
        time++;
      }

     // This says if timer is 60 seconds, add a minute, reset time!
     if(time == 60){
        ++Minute;
        clockTicker = 0;
     }
    } // end if
}
```

Comment: I think doing the zero-padding with `setw` and `setfill` should also work when writing to a file. In this case, there is no difference to writing to std::cout.

Comment: Remember though, it also outputs the message using sets and setfill, it doesn't save it into the variable though.

Comment: yes, it is not possible to store the zeros in the variable this way. That's because the type of the variable is a **number**. And numbers are stored without leading zeros. So you have to add the zeros every time you want to output the number.

Comment: well, I can at least going with using the setw and setfill method for display the timer, but the real question is, how can I add the zero into the text document?

Comment: that depends on how you write into the text document. Variant a: open the text document as a `std::ofstream`, then write to this stream the *same* way as to `std::cout` and use setw and setfill (see the answer of Lightning Racis in Orbit)

Comment: Please [do not destroy your questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288748/is-the-original-poster-of-an-answer-allowed-to-destructively-edit-his-own-conten).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Wouldn't a simple if statement do the job?

```
int main()
{
    string separator; // separator variable
    while(stoptimer == false)
    {
        clickTime(clockTicker,loopRepeats,Time);
        loopRepeats++;
        CPos(0, 0); cout << " Time is:         ";
        if(clockTicker < 10) // check if it is neccesary to adapt the separator
            separator = ":0"; // include a 0 in the separator
        else
            separator = ":"; // else don't

        cout << Minute << separator << clockTicker; // use a variable instead of a set value

        Sleep(100);     // This is the game of the game's speed
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this same solution

Comment: He already has it working for `cout` and, crucially, he has it working _properly_ using `iomanip` rather than this hack! The question is about how to do the same in a text file.

Comment: I do believe @LightningRacisinObrit has much more general answer. This also requires additional code each time you want to output the number, so there is no benefit

Answer (score 5):

You don't.

Numbers are numbers are numbers are numbers. Not decimal, human-readable representations. They are *numbers*. They don't have zero-padding. Zero-padding only affects *serialisation*.

You have correctly discovered how to zero-pad a number when you serialise it into `std::cout`; now simply do the same when you serialise it into a `std::ofstream`. They are both output streams, with the same interface: that you're streaming into a text file rather than to console does not matter.

Comment: Well in my case, I want the zero padding because thats how a real display clock works. It doesn't say 5:5, when the time is actually 5:05.

Comment: @Ryan12345: Yes, I understand why you want zero-padding in the serialised output. Please read the answer more carefully!